# MongoDB Pool size vs Pool timeout

Tags: ruby, mongodb, connection-pooling

When to increase either pool size or timeout or both? Just trying to understand best practice, I'm starting to get a lot of `could not obtain connection within 5.0 seconds. The max pool size is currently 1; consider increasing the pool size or timeout. (Mongo::ConnectionTimeoutError)` errors, and want to know rule of thumb.

Comment: Now it's about time :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Demetrius Michael,

pool configuration is based on your system usage, and can change during your application lifecycle, you will need to practice pool tuning in a regular:

monitor -> tuning -> test -> monitor...

You can use JMeter to test you connection pool according to your current/future scenario

You can see some best practices here: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html

Regards,
Moacy